# Probleme d'emplacement

Tags: css

Bonjour à tous et à toutes je me permets de faire appel à vous car je rencontre une petite difficulté :

J’ai actuellement installé la protection captchaV2 sur mon plug-in wpforms-lite et admin-custom-login . Tout fonctionne parfaitement.

Le problème qui se pose et que depuis que je viens installer la protection antispam l’icône de recaptcha s’afiche lorsque l’on accède au formulaire de contacts ce qui est tout à fait normal et d’ailleurs je compte bien le garder. Le problème qu’il se pose et que ce logo est positionné en bas à droite du site Internet et mon thème WordPress  dispose d’une option scrollup . donc quand vous descendez tout en bas de la page de mon site Internet une icône apparaît et quand on clique dessus le site Internet retourne tous en hault .

L’icône rechaptcha est donc en superposition sur le logo scroll up lorsque l’on descend en bas de page .

Je voudrais donc remonter Je voudrais donc remonterez logo de recaptcha

Quelle ligne de code modifier et quel code est à ajouter?

https://www.rectimo16.fr/contactez-nous/

Merci d’avance à vous tous

Comment: Probléme Résolut ajouter dans le css de sont theme. .grecaptcha-badge { 
    bottom:65px !important; 
}

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Please ask your question in English so it will be accessible to wider audience, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange